# C# changing double value 0.0 to 0

Tags: c#

The value 0.0 is changing to 0 when I assign it to a double variable. Is there any workaround to preserve the decimal and succeeding 0's if any?

Edit:

```
   double dt = 0.0;
   Console.WriteLine(dt);
   //Output:0
```

Comment: A double is just a number, it has no concept of how it should be displayed. If you want to control how it's turned into a string, you do that at the point that you turn it into a string. E.g. by passing a format string to `ToString()`, or using a format specifier in an interpolated string, etc

Comment: post the code, maybe you are doing something that is changing the variable

Comment: You may want to try `decimal` instead of `double`: `decimal d = 0.0m; Console.Write(d);` prints `"0.0"`, if you put `d = 0m;` or `d = 0.00m` you'll get `0` and `0.00` as the output

Comment: Try `Console.WriteLine("{0:0.0}", dt)`. [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the-0-custom-specifier)

Comment: Constraints: Cant change type from double

Comment: [The reason is that Console.WriteLine casts the value .ToString() without any particular formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 2):

You can provide the desired *format*:

```
double dt = 0.0;
Console.WriteLine($"{dt:f1}");
```

Here `f1` stands for `1` digit after decimal point.

As an alternative (esp. if you are working finance) you can change the type, from `double` to `decimal`:

```
decimal dt = 0.0m;
Console.WriteLine(dt);
```